# Multi column index with date field

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a 3-column composite index on a table below defined using SqlAlchemy and Postgres. I'm trying to figure out what order to make the `internal_date` and `email_id` to make the query the most efficient. Or if I need the composite index at all.

I want to query by `folder_id` and get the most recent 100 emails. If I order the index by `folder_id`, `internal_date` and then `email_id` that would appear to be the most logical, but I'm not sure if applying the composite index like this will work well or I should just have a single index on each column?

This model assumes there are many thousands of `folder_ids` and millions of `email_ids`. (i.e. a folder can have many emails)

```
class EmailMessages(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "email_message_mapped_model"

    folder_id = db.Column(
        sa.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey("folders.folder_id", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        primary_key=True,
    )

    email_id = db.Column(
        sa.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey("emails.email_id", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        primary_key=True,
    )

    internal_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

Indexes:

```
    __table_args__ = (
        db.Index(
            'ix_index1',
            folder_id, email_id, internal_date
        ),
    )
```

OR

```
    __table_args__ = (
        db.Index(
            'ix_index2',
            folder_id, internal_date, email_id
        ),
    )
```

OR

```
    __table_args__ = (
        db.Index(
            'ix_index3a',
            folder_id,
        ),
        db.Index(
            'ix_index3b',
            internal_date,
        ),
        db.Index(
            'ix_index3c',
            email_id,
        ),

    )
```

Comment: You can (and should) measure this yourself by using explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for your SQL statements. Create the different indexes, test, measure and check the next one.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I do not believe it is possible to get postgres to use a specific index or any index at all for that matter. I was asking this question to see if someone with experience with such indexes had faced a similar problem.

Comment: ix_index2 makes sense to me but you have to test it to see the results. It depends on your data and your queries, we don’t have this.

Comment: You are correct that it is basically not possible to force Postgres to use a specific index. But if Postgres does not select the index it is a pretty good indication that it is not the correct index  anyway.